# Adding multiple rows recursively

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `river` with three columns: `name`,`river` and `length`.

`name` is the name of the river, `river` is the river that this river connects to and `length` is the length of the river

A sample table could look like this:

```
name       | river      | length
           |            |  
Amazonas   |            | 3778
Rio negro  | Amazonas   | 2886
Huallaga   | Rio Negro  | 1138
Nile       |            | 3090
White Nile | Sobat      | 950
Sobat      | White Nile | 740
```

I want to **recursively** add together the lengths of the rivers which I have done here:

```
with recursive cte as(
select name, river,length from river
where name = 'Amazonas'
Union all
select r.name,r.river,r.length from river r
join cte s on r.river = s.name
)
select sum(length) from cte;
```

However I also want to able to add together different parent rivers and group them accordingly like so:

```
name       combined_length
Amazonas | 7802
Nile     | 6203
Volga    | 6234
```

I have tried to add `or` statements to my code above like so:

```
where name = 'Amazonas' or name = 'Nile' or name = 'Volga'
```

But then I couldn't group them by their parent, I could only add all the lengths together of every river (Amazonas, Nile and Volga combined) or not adding them at all if I tried to use group by.

I have also tried to make three different subqueries with:

```
length from river
where name = 'Amazonas'
Union all
select r.name,r.river,r.length from river r
join cte s on r.river = s.name
```

and replacing name with the rivers I want, but then I get the error:

```
recursive query "cte" does not have the form non-recursive-term UNION [ALL] recursive-term
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting something like this to get the lengths of all parent rivers:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select name, river, length, name as parent
      from river r
      where r.river is null
      union all
      select r.name, r.river, r.length, cte.parent
      from river r join
           cte s
           on r.river = s.name
     )
select parent, sum(length)
from cte
group by parent;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!!